# Does the amount of IN parameters change the execution plan of a query?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

Let's consider those queries:

```
select * from person where com_code in (1, 2, 3, 4)
select * from person where com_code in (1, 2, 2, 2)
select * from person where com_code in (1, 2, 3)
select * from person where com_code in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
```

Do they have different execution plan stored in Oracle's memory?
In other words, does the amount of IN parameters change the execution plan?
Will there be an execution plan for 1 parameter, another one for 2 parameters, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will there be an execution plan for 1 parameter, another one for 2 parameters, etc.?

The SQL engine will check the text of the query and see if it is identical to an existing query:

- If it is identical then it will use the existing plan.
- If there are any differences then it will parse the new query and generate a new plan.

For your examples, there will be one execution plan for each query regardless of the number of parameters as the query text is different for each query. So there would be 4 different execution plans for the 4 different queries.

---

If you use bind parameters:

```sql
select * from person where com_code in (:a, :b, :c, :d);
```

and you pass in `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` or you pass in `2`, `2`, `2` and `2` then the SQL engine will see that the text of the second query is identical to the first and, assuming that the table statistics are unchanged, will re-use the execution plan from the first query for the second (even though the bind variables are different).

If you vary the number of bind parameters then a different execution plan will be generated to match the number of filters.

---

If you do not use bind parameters then the SQL engine will have to parse text of the query with each change and may not generate the same query plan.

For example:

```sql
select * from person where com_code in (2, 2, 2, 2);
```

Will be rewritten by the SQL engine to:

```sql
select * from person where com_code = 2;
```

and would generate a different explain plan to:

```sql
select * from person where com_code in (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8c639a3468b2be3add7f2e5fe927363f) (Remember to expand the explain plans to see the full details)*

Answer (score 0):

My test in SQL Developer shows that the cost of the query will be larger when more parameters are in in operator.

One value:

[image]
[image]

Two values:

[image]
[image]

Three values:

[image]
[image]

So, to answer your question: "Does the amount of IN parameters change the execution plan of a query?" YES.

This can also help: [How efficiently does Oracle handle a very long IN operator list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690974/how-efficiently-does-oracle-handle-a-very-long-in-operator-list)

Comment: This answer is not an explanation but an observation.

Comment: This answer is not useful?

Comment: Cost is just the optimiser's estimate for the resources required to execute the statement. It thinks it will take more resources to process two values than one. That may result in a different plan, or it may not. Your test doesn't show the plan hash value, so we don't know.

Comment: Arent the images under the cost images the plan images?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the execution plan changes. First of all, the conditions are part of the plan. So checking whether `id in (1,2)` or `id in (1,2,3)` means two different comparisons and hence two different plans. The general plan, though, which tables to access in which order and by what means can be the same.

But the don't have to be the same, so even the route Oracle decides for can change. Take a table of 1000 rows for instance and a query with `where id in (...)`. If the `IN` clause contains one or two IDs, Oracle will use the index. With all thousand IDs in the `IN` clause, Oracle will decide for a full table scan instead.

```
select * from thousandrows where id in (1,2); -- index
select * from thousandrows where id in (1,...,1000); -- full table scan
```

And as to the plans in Oracle's memory, I see from `V$SQL_PLAN`that Oracle stores the plans per query. So with two queries with the exact same execution plan like these two:

```
select * from thousandrows where id in (1,2);
select * from thousandrows where id = 1 or id = 2;
```

Oracle will still have two copies of that same plan in memory, one for each query.

Comment: Oracle can still decide to use an index with all 1000 ids. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9a188fca90e1cc146f33c4e81f7b00ff) gives two examples where bind variables are and are not used; when 1000 bind variables are used then it will use the index but when the 1000 values are hardcoded then it uses a full table scan.

Comment: @MT0 you shouldn't trust an explain plan with bind variables https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/nid60fyugq4vscuywle2s29c3